# How to place 3D object correctly in ARSCNView using ARKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I am long time trying to place 3D object in correct position in SceneView, the object adding in SceneView correctly, but its position turning right or left side,

```
func addObject(x: Float = 0, y: Float = 0, z: Float = -0.5) {

    guard let shipScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/house.scn"),
        let shipNode = shipScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "house", recursively: false)
    else {
        return
    }
    shipNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
    shipNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shipNode)
}
```

This is the code I added, whether this issue related to camera position, I have changed that too, it doesn't seem work.
Kindly refer attached image for example.

[image]

How to place the object correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems that you need to adjust the rotation of your model so that it will be positioned correctly.

Seeing as it is an `scn file` you should be able to do this in in the `SceneKit Editor` within `Xcode` by adjusting the `Euler Angles` of the model.

Which for your information refer to the following:

> Pitch (the x component) is the rotation about the node’s x-axis.
>
> Yaw (the y component) is the rotation about the node’s y-axis.
>
> Roll (the z component) is the rotation about the node’s z-axis.

[image]

Here is an example, illustrating the effects of changing the `X Eular Angle` within the `SceneKit Editor`:

[image]

[image]

If you wanted to do this programatically you can do this a number of ways:

(a) *By Modifying the Eular Angles Of The Model e.g.*

```
shipNode.eulerAngles.x = 90
shipNode.eulerAngles.y = 45
shipNode.eulerAngles.z = 90
```

(b) *By Using An `SCNVector4` which is a*:

> four-component rotation vector specifying the direction of the
>   rotation axis in the first three components and the angle of rotation
>   (in radians) in the fourth.

As such an example of using this would be as follows:

```
///Rotate The Ship 45 Degrees Around It's Y Axis
shipNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi / 4)
```

In order to make life a bit easier, you can also use the following extension so that you can write your desired rotation in degrees and then convert to radians which is needed for an SCNVector4 e.g:

```
shipNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, Float(Int(45).degreesToRadians)))

extension  CGFloat{

  /// Converts Degrees To Radians
  var degreesToRadians:CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) * .pi/180}

}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Great @josh..Worked perfectly, well explained..Lots of Thanks.